# How to create ArrayField in TortoiseORM

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, fastapi, tortoise-orm

How to create ArrayField() in TortoiseORM

```
from common.base_model import AbstractBaseModel
from tortoise.fields import CharField, BooleanField, ForeignKeyField, ArrayField


class City(AbstractBaseModel): 
    name = CharField(max_length=100, unique=True) 
    district = CharField(max_length=100, null=True) 
    state = CharField(max_length=100) 
    country = ArrayField() # not working 
    is_verified = BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Try to improve your question. Have you tried anything different? Where did you find the `ArrayField`? Did you try to read a  *TortoiseORM* documentation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ArrayField` in *TortoiseORM*, here is an [article](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html) about fields in *TortoiseORM* from its documentation.

As you can see, there is no matching field in *TortoiseORM*, so you have to [extend](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#extending-a-field) the existing field class.
I suggest extending the basic class `Field` because your subclass' `to_db_value` method has to return the same type as extended field class' `to_db_value` method, and in the class `Field` it's not specified.

---

Next time, try harder - read the documentation and make better questions (add more info, show your attempts).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you want,which I'm assuming is having a field to hold multiple countries, you'd have to create another table for your `country` field and have a many to many relationship between that table and your `city` table,its a more conventional implementation that wont have you extend the existing field class.